# How can convert data that I have stored as a string into a map

Tags: string, grails

I have one String stored in my DDBB, for example in my column data I have this String: `"name=James castle&age=20"` and I want, in my Services, converted to a map

I'm trying something like:

```
List <NameValuePair> parameters = myDomainInstance.data
if (org.externalDeliveryParameters){
    parameters = URLEncodedUtils.parse(org.externalDeliveryParameters,
                                       StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
}
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot cast object 'name=James castle&age=20' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.List'
```

Somebody know how can i do it with `List<NameValuePair>` or another form?

Comment: Are you sure that `myDomainInstance.data` is of type `String`.

Comment: @Salva, note that URLEncodedUtils.parse doesn't transform the string into a map. This method transforms a String in a ArrayList where each object of the ArrayList is a NameValuePair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you really wanted to write something like this

```
List <NameValuePair> parameters 
if (myDomainInstance.data) {
   parameters = URLEncodedUtils.parse(myDomainInstance.data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
}
```

That's based on input and output params.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
s = "name=James castle&age=20"

def map = s.split('&').inject([:]) {result, kv-> def (key, value) = kv.split('=').toList(); result[key] = value != null ? value : null; result }
```

If you're storing URLs in your database then you need to use the decordeURL() method provided by Grails, check below:

```
def map = s.split('&').inject([:]) {result, kv-> def (key, value) = kv.split('=').toList(); result[key] = value != null ? value.decodeURL() : null; result }
```

Answer (score 0):

use simple regexp

```
def m = [:]
'name=James castle&age=20'.eachMatch( /([^&=]+)=([^&=]+)/ ){ m[ it[ 1 ] ] = it[ 2 ] }
assert m == [name:'James castle', age:'20']
```